# How can I get a field from each element of a list of custom data types in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, knapsack-problem

First of all, if the title is confusing I apologise - I don't know how to phrase it.

I'm learning Haskell and tackling the [Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) but having a problem with list comprehension.

```
data Object = Item { name :: String,
            weight:: Double,
            profit :: Double,
            efficiency :: Double }
            deriving (Read, Show)
```

I have a function that takes a list from a .csv file and calculates efficiency and sorts it:

```
getItemsAsList
    = do
    body <- readFile "items.csv"
    let ls = split '\n' body
    let lc = map (split ',') ls
    let itemList = map (loadItem) lc
    let sorted = sortItems efficiency itemList
    return sorted
```

Functions used:

```
loadItem :: [[Char]] -> Object
loadItem (n:ow:op:xs) = Item n w p (p/w)
    where
        w = read ow :: Double
        p = read op :: Double

sortItems :: Ord a => (t -> a) -> [t] -> [t]
sortItems fn [ ] = [ ]
sortItems fn (pivot:rest)
    = sortItems fn [x | x <- rest, (fn x) > (fn pivot)]
        ++ [pivot] ++
        sortItems fn [x | x <- rest, (fn x) <= (fn pivot)]

split :: Char -> [Char] -> [[Char]]
split _ [] = []
split delim str = if before == [] then
    split delim (drop 1 remainder)
    else
        before: split delim (drop 1 remainder)
    where
        (before, remainder) = span (/=delim) str
```

What I am trying to do is write a function that will go through the list returned by the `getItemsAsList` function and get the value of the `weight` field from each element and sum them together. From this I can hopefully implement the greedy solution to the problem, once I understand how to get the elements.

Also, the `getItemsAsList` function returns `IO [Object]`

Thanks.

Comment: liftM (sum . map weight) getItemsAsList :: IO Double

Answer (score 2):

To get the weight from a single `Object`, you do `weight obj`.  Thus, to get the weight from each element of a list of `Object`s, you do `map weight objlist` or `[weight obj | obj <- objlist]`.  Also, the `Prelude` has a `sum` function which works exactly as you'd expect.  Put them all together, and you're done.

Comment: That sounds like it would work, but the following error comes from trying that:

`Couldn't match expected type '[Object]' with actual type 'IO [Object]'`

Comment: @FelixWeir: That's because `getItemsAsList` returns a result in the `IO` monad.  Do you know how to do non-IO operations on an IO value?  How exactly do you intend to combine `getItemsAsList` with this new function, anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You are treating the result of `getItemsAsList`, which is a monadic function, as a normal value instead of as an IO action.

The concept of a monad is usually explained as it being a box, which you can "unpack" the value from (using the `<-` operator). When you call it from a pure function, you cannot unpack the value, and instead are just left with the box. (that is what the `IO [Object]` is, it is an IO box containing an Object list value). You can however, freely use pure functions from inside a monad.

The solution is to call and unpack the value of `getItemsAsList` from within a monad, and then pass it onto your other pure functions to carry out whatever the rest of your task is.

Once you have unpacked the list of objects from getItemsAsList using the `<-` operator, you can pass it into other pure functions.